# I filling the fields but do not enter in form.is_valid ():

Tags: django

Experts I am waiting for my problem to be solved on the internet

Why when I finished filling the fields in django do not enter in form.is_valid (): Although the results are presented correctly I hope to solve this problem

```
class Listing(models.Model):
  property_type = models.IntegerField(choices=PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICES, default=1)
  user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                           on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  price = models.BigIntegerField()
  roomsTotal = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
  Bathrooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
  bedrooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
  Receptionrooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
  livingArea = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=1)
  lotSize = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=1)
  unitType = models.IntegerField(choices=UNIT_TYPE_CHOICES, default=1)

  VOnSea = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)

yearBuilt = models.PositiveIntegerField(
            validators=[
                MinValueValidator(1900),
                MaxValueValidator(datetime.datetime.now().year)],
            help_text="Use the following format: <YYYY>")

  hoaPrice = models.BigIntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
  groundTankSize = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=1,null=True,blank=True)
  garageSize = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=1,null=True,blank=True)
  homeDescription = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

```
class ForSaleForm(forms.Form):
    property_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=PROPERTY_TYPE_CHOICES,required=False)
    price = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    roomsTotal = forms.IntegerField()
    Bathrooms = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    bedrooms = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    Receptionrooms = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
    livingArea = forms.DecimalField(required=True)
    lotSize = forms.DecimalField(required=True)
    unitType = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=UNIT_TYPE_CHOICES,required=False)
    yearBuilt = forms.DateField(required=True)

    def clean(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        if data.get('price', None) or (data.get('Bathrooms', None) and data.get('bedrooms', None)):
            return data
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Provide either a price and Bathrooms or a bedrooms')
```

```
      form = ForSaleForm(request.POST or None)
      for key in request.POST.keys():
          if key != 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
              print(key,":",request.POST[key])
      if form.is_valid():
        propertyType = form.cleaned_data.get('propertyType')
        price = form.cleaned_data.get('price')
        roomsTotal = form.cleaned_data.get('roomsTotal')
        Bathrooms = form.cleaned_data.get('Bathrooms')
        bedrooms = form.cleaned_data.get('bedrooms')
        Receptionrooms = form.cleaned_data.get('Receptionrooms')
        livingArea = form.cleaned_data.get('livingArea')
        lotSize = form.cleaned_data.get('lotSize')
        unitType = form.cleaned_data.get('unitType')
        yearBuilt = form.cleaned_data.get('yearBuilt')

        listing = Listing(
          user=request.user,
          price=price,
          roomsTotal=roomsTotal,
          Bathrooms=Bathrooms,
          bedrooms=bedrooms,
          Receptionrooms=Receptionrooms,
          livingArea=livingArea,
          lotSize=lotSize,
          unitType=unitType,
          yearBuilt=yearBuilt,
          remodelYear=remodelYear
        )
        listing.save()
        print("saved listing")
```

request.POST Output: propertyType : 1 price : 443 roomsTotal : 44 Bathrooms : 5454 bedrooms : 44 Receptionrooms : 55 livingArea : 45 lotSize : 4334 unitType : 2 yearBuilt : 11 hoaPrice : groundTankSize : garageSize : homeDescription : terms : on

When you press the send button, the form refresh without showing verification messages so that it is supposed to not respond to the wrong information

```
<div class="md-form mb-5">
                  <input type='text' placeholder='حدد السعر الخاص بك' id='price' name='price' class='form-control'/>
                  <label for="price" class="">السعر</label>
                    {{ form.price.errors }}
                </div>
```

Thanking your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

add {% csrf_token %} before form.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```